# Confused by python's unicode regex errors

Tags: python, unicode

Can someone explain why the middle code excerpt in python 2.7x throws an error?

```
import re
walden = "Waldenström"
walden
print(walden)

s1 = "ö"
s2 = "Wal"
s3 = "OOOOO"

out = re.sub(s1, s3, walden)
print(out)

out = re.sub("W", "w", walden)
print(out)

# I need this one to work
out = re.sub('W', u'w', walden)
# ERROR

out = re.sub(u'W', 'w', walden)
print(out)

out = re.sub(s2, s1, walden)
print(out)
```

I'm very confused and have tried reading the manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`walden` is a `str`:

```
walden = "Waldenström"
```

This code replaces a character with a `unicode` string:

```
re.sub('W', u'w', walden)
```

The result of that should be `u'w' + "aldenström"`. This is the part that fails.

In order to concatenate `str` and `unicode`, both have to be first converted to `unicode`. The result is `unicode` as well.

The problem is, the interpreter does not know how to convert `'ö'` to unicode, because it does not know which encoding to use. The result is ambiguous.

The solution is to convert yourself before doing the replacement:

```
re.sub('W', u'w', unicode(walden, encoding))
```

The `encoding` should be the one you use to create that file, e.g.

```
re.sub('W', u'w', unicode(walden, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you! That clarified a lot and now the documentation make better sense, too!